# When do you say skin and when the skin?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

According to my American friend, "you can have glowing skin" but "cream makes the skin softer" and "smth penetrates into the skin".
Is there some rule I can use to understand when "the" is needed? 
What about "brightens or soothes(the) skin", etc?

What if it is "skin tone" or "skin tone and texture"?